# How to round off to 4 decimal places in SQL in such a way that zero gets appended if we have less that 4 digits after the coma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, formatting, rounding

4.145 should be 4.1450, and 4.124489 be 4.1245, I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: cast(x as decimal(14,4))

Comment: Have you tried @jarlh's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A trailing zero can only exist in a string representation of a numerical value. In SQL Server you can use [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT FORMAT(4.145, '0.0000')
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f85b3/3)

Comment: it says :  "FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @Wicky then you're not using SQL Server 2012 - see the documentation link in my answer.

Comment: As @jarlh suggested This will give trailing zeros: SELECT cast(1.55 as decimal(14,4))

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that's correct, though I don't see the point here. storage is irrelevant (in the end it's all bits) and the only way to notice the trailing zero is in a string representation. For that purpose, `FORMAT()` is a valid option.

Answer (score -2):

Do it like this:

```
declare @num as float;
set @num=5.20;

select convert(decimal(10, 2), @num);
```

Or instead search this:

Float datatype with 2 digits after decimal point

[Try to understand this one](http://%20[1]:%20https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56451/float-datatype-with-2-digits-after-decimal-point)

Comment: What is the meaning of the '10'?

Comment: Not floating point type, decimal type... (decimal(10,2 ) means total number of 10 digits, where 2 digits are after the decimal point.)